# JPA ColumnTransformer write is not working

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

this is my entity.

```
@Getter 
@Setter
@Entity 
@Table(name = "crypt_test_table") 
@IdClass(value = SqlFunctionTest.class) public class SqlFunctionTest implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "name")
        @ColumnTransformer(
                forColumn = "name",
                read = "CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name, get_enc_key() ,get_aes_init_vector()) USING utf8)",
                write = "AES_ENCRYPT(?, get_enc_key(), get_aes_init_vector())"
        )
        private String name;
    
    }
```

I m trying to insert and select by encrypt and decrypt which I declared on my entity.
when I read it, it worked. like this.

```
SELECT
    SQLFUNCTIO0_.ID AS ID1_13_,
    SQLFUNCTIO0_.NAME AS NAME2_13_ 
FROM
    CRYPT_TEST_TABLE SQLFUNCTIO0_ 
WHERE
    CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(SQLFUNCTIO0_.NAME, GET_ENC_KEY() ,GET_AES_INIT_VECTOR()) USING UTF8)='TROY.T'
```

but when i save an entity, it doesn't work like this.

```
INSERT 
INTO
    CRYPT_TEST_TABLE
    (ID, NAME) 
VALUES
    (NULL, 'TROY.T')
```

This is the test code I did.

```
@Test
public void testSave(){
    System.out.println("JPA TEST");
    SqlFunctionTest entity = new SqlFunctionTest();
    entity.setName("troy.t");
    jpaCryptoService.save(entity);
}
@Test
public void testSelect(){
    List<SqlFunctionTest> op =  jpaCryptoService.findByName("troy.t");
    System.out.println("op = " + op);
}
```

What's wrong with me?

```
2022-07-11T10:27:02.091+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [kground-preinit] o.h.v.i.u.Version                        : HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.2.3.Final
2022-07-11T10:27:02.126+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] ApplicationTest                          : Starting ApplicationTest using Java 11.0.14.1 on TroyTui-MacBookPro.local with PID 25748
2022-07-11T10:27:03.188+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-07-11T10:27:03.592+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 399 ms. Found 122 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-07-11T10:27:04.501+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-07-11T10:27:04.751+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-07-11T10:27:04.829+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper                      : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-07-11T10:27:04.867+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] o.h.Version                              : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-07-11T10:27:04.996+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] o.h.a.c.Version                          : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-07-11T10:27:05.073+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] o.h.d.Dialect                            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2022-07-11T10:27:05.564+09:00  WARN 25748 --- [           main] o.h.m.RootClass                          : HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.dktechin.saas.smartfactory.test.SqlFunctionTest
2022-07-11T10:27:05.564+09:00  WARN 25748 --- [           main] o.h.m.RootClass                          : HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.dktechin.saas.smartfactory.test.SqlFunctionTest
2022-07-11T10:27:06.228+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-07-11T10:27:06.233+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-07-11T10:27:10.167+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] o.e.j.u.log                              : Logging initialized @9863ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2022-07-11T10:27:11.211+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] ApplicationTest                          : Started ApplicationTest in 9.59 seconds (JVM running for 10.908)
JPA TEST
2022-07-11T10:27:11.393+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] p6spy                                    : 
    SELECT
        SQLFUNCTIO0_.ID AS ID1_13_0_,
        SQLFUNCTIO0_.NAME AS NAME2_13_0_ 
    FROM
        CRYPT_TEST_TABLE SQLFUNCTIO0_ 
    WHERE
        SQLFUNCTIO0_.ID=NULL 
        AND SQLFUNCTIO0_.NAME='TROY.T'

    Connection ID: 2
    Execution Time: 24 ms

    Call Stack (number 1 is entry point): 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-07-11T10:27:11.443+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] p6spy                                    : 
    INSERT 
    INTO
        CRYPT_TEST_TABLE
        (ID, NAME) 
    VALUES
        (NULL, 'TROY.T')

    Connection ID: 2
    Execution Time: 14 ms

    Call Stack (number 1 is entry point): 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-07-11T10:27:11.602+09:00  INFO 25748 --- [           main] p6spy                                    : 
    SELECT
        SQLFUNCTIO0_.ID AS ID1_13_,
        SQLFUNCTIO0_.NAME AS NAME2_13_ 
    FROM
        CRYPT_TEST_TABLE SQLFUNCTIO0_ 
    WHERE
        CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(SQLFUNCTIO0_.NAME, GET_ENC_KEY() ,GET_AES_INIT_VECTOR()) USING UTF8)='TROY.T'

    Connection ID: 3
    Execution Time: 14 ms

    Call Stack (number 1 is entry point): 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
op = []
```

Comment: Please supply stack trace

Comment: @Llama I copy and paste it, but I don't know how to be shown pretty..